# Como eliminar valores repetidos em uma coluna de texto no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho um data.frame que possui uma coluna com nomes, porém estes nomes se repetem algumas vezes. Preciso criar uma nova coluna em um novo data.frame com todos os nomes, porém sem repetições.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supondo que seu data frame se chama `dados` e a coluna com estes nomes se chama `nomes`, faça

```
unique(dados$nomes)
```

Se quiser saber o número de vezes que cada nome aparece, faça

```
table(dados$nomes)
```

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso que precisava. Entre fazer minha pergunta e ver sua resposta, acabei fazendo um caminho mais comprido utilizando 'levels(as.factor(dados$nomes))'. Mas adotei sua solução.

Comment: Que bom que tu havia conseguido chegar numa resposta correta e independente da minha. Se possível, aceite a minha resposta para que, futuramente, outras pessoas possam se beneficiar dela também.